# А в чем смысл юнит тестов?

Tags: java, junit

Вот подскажите, делаю пет проект, есть обычные контроллеры, сервисы и репозитории. И вот я не пойму, какой смысл покрывать методы в сервисе, если там придется все замокать, описать поведение мока и сравнить ответ с заранее определенным поведением. Может есть что почитать по теме, а то везде попадаются только примеры с тестами метода, выполняющие 2 + 2.

Comment: Мокаете вход, а проверяете выход. Суть теста проверить что код делает именно то что задумано для всего спектра входных данных. Например покрываете метод "сложение", на вход 2 и 2, на выходе должно быть 4 (2+2). Но ведь 2*2 тоже 4, значит добавим еще один тест для 3 и 3 на входе, на выходе должно быть 6.

Comment: А ещё тестами покрывается получение на вход заведомо некорректных и "пограничных" данных. В случае 2+2 вместо одного из чисел можно получить null и выполнение метода (в зависимости от заложенной логики) либо обязательно должно свалиться с вполне конкретной ошибкой, либо посчитать null за 0 и вернуть результат 2. Но скорее всего в логике должно быть "свалиться с ошибкой". И то, что метод действительно валится действительно с нужным исключением - тоже проверяется.

Comment: Ну с методами 2 + 2 понятно. Но какой смысл, если сервис метод, сохраняет сущность в бд, если ты сам определяешь поведение
when(serviceMock.save(entity))
  .thenReturn(1);
assertThat(result).isEqualTo(1);

Comment: В этом случае ты можешь проверить что сохранение вызвалось с нужным entry. Но если у вас действительно абсолютно тривиальный метод (типа `save(entry) { db.save(entry) }` то наверное ему не нужен юнит-тест

Comment: Стоп. Если вы тестируете метод service.save(...) то мокать надо не его. Мокать надо вызов репозитория или feign-клиента или всего чего угодно, что автовайрится в этот сервис. Чтобы по всем вызовам "вовне" получить однозначное четко заданное поведение и оставить тестируемой только логику самого метода.